# Python help in ImportError: No module named google

Tags: python

I have found this link http://machinespirit.net/acegiak/2012/07/10/qad-normalized-google-distance/#comments which seems to interest me with the python codes. What I did I created a new g1.py file copy the codes into it. Then I chmod 755 and then ./g1.py and I got the following error.

```
./g1.py test test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./g1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google import gsearch
ImportError: No module named google
```

Comment: Have you installed `google` module?

Comment: google is not comming with python, you should install it first

Comment: How to install google I am very new to python?

Comment: This is not a question about _using_ a Python module, but a question about _installing_ a Python module. Thus system administration, thus off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of the linked document.
That code snippet uses the in-house google module which is not public and is intended to show the algorithm at work not the full implementation of the functionality.

I have since updated the document to include a basic cut-down version of the gsearch function the full code with this addition looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from google import gsearch
import math,sys
import json
import urllib

def gsearch(searchfor):
  query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
  url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
  search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
  search_results = search_response.read()
  results = json.loads(search_results)
  data = results['responseData']
  return data

args = sys.argv[1:]
m = 45000000000
if len(args) != 2:
        print "need two words as arguments"
        exit
n0 = int(gsearch(args[0])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
n1 = int(gsearch(args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
n2 = int(gsearch(args[0]+" "+args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
l1 = max(math.log10(n0),math.log10(n1))-math.log10(n2)
l2 = math.log10(m)-min(math.log10(n0),math.log10(n1))
distance = l1/l2
print distance
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the `google` Python module. I didn't find any module named like this. I think the module required is http://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/. So you might have to replace the first import by:

```
from pygoogle import search
```

Or ask the post author where he gets his module.

Comment: how to install it I am very new to python? I have gone to the site http://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/ but it as me to go here for more details results http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-translate/ where I was trying to play with it too but also got stuck with this sort of error.

Comment: I followed the link python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
copying pygoogle.py -> build/lib Next I did this python setup.py build
running build
running build_py

Comment: Lastly tried but same error ./g1.py test1 test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./g1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pygoogle import gsearch
ImportError: No module named pygoogle